# Using alias declaration with VC++ 11

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Following code example using alias declaration new in C++11 fails to compile with VC++ 11, update 1 in VS2012 and emits included errors. It compiles and executes without a peep with GCC 4.7.2 under MinGW on Windows 7 using `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall in.cpp`.

I didn't find any indications that this isn't supported. Furthermore, IntelliSense doesn't pick up any errors and displays a tooltip for `cdptr` type that says `typedef const double *cdptr`. My project is set to use v110 platform toolset and compile as C++ code.

How have I wronged Microsoft?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using cdptr = const double*;

    const double pi = 3.14159;
    cdptr cdp = &pi;

    std::cout << "cdp: " << (*cdp) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: AliasDeclTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  AliasDeclTest.cpp
1>f:\aliasdecltest\aliasdecltest.cpp(9): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '='
1>f:\aliasdecltest\aliasdecltest.cpp(9): error C2873: 'cdptr' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>f:\aliasdecltest\aliasdecltest.cpp(12): error C2065: 'cdptr' : undeclared identifier
1>f:\aliasdecltest\aliasdecltest.cpp(12): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cdp'
1>f:\aliasdecltest\aliasdecltest.cpp(12): error C2065: 'cdp' : undeclared identifier
1>f:\aliasdecltest\aliasdecltest.cpp(14): error C2065: 'cdp' : undeclared identifier
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Pretty sure VC++11 doesn't support using alias declarations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*MSVC11*, even with the *November CTP*, does **not** implement using alias declarations.

You can find a table of *C++11* support [here](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport).

Comment: My reading lead me to believe that it was **template** alias (parameterized type alias) that were not supported, not everything in N2258. But if the correct reading is that everything in that document isn't supported by MSVC11, then it's case solved.

Comment: @MartinshShaiters: Yes, the entire thing. To be fair, the entire motivation for the feature is the template portion, so it's highly unlikely any compiler would implement it without (that would just be typedef).

Comment: @GManNickG Yes. But it's a very neat syntax for a typdef! :)

Answer (score 6):

Based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx), it appears Visual Studio 2012 does not yet support type aliases.