# Get pointer to class method with 'using' keyword

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, inheritance

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Why can't I get a pointer to a class method which was "upgraded" to public in a child class?

The following code does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Parent {
protected:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "Parent::foo()\n";
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    //void foo() { Parent::foo(); } //This compiles
    using Parent::foo; //This does NOT compile
};
int main() {
    Child c;

    std::function < void () > f = std::bind(&Child::foo, &c);
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the error:

```
error C2248: 'Parent::foo' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'Parent'
```

Comment: They are different methods. using Parent::foo makes an alias of Parent::foo as Child::foo, and the public there makes it so that anyone can access the alias: it does nothing to change Parent::foo.

Comment: Dunno what the problem is, but maybe use a compliant compiler built in this decade? [See it live.](http://ideone.com/vzEj2y). You say you're using VS2010, perhaps upgrade that to 2012 (with the November 2012 CTP). Or an appropriate gcc or clang (but if your a VS guy, that isn't likely).

Comment: The code compiles fine under TDM-GCC (MINGW) 4.7.1 when the line `std::function < void () > f = std::bind(&Child::foo, &c);` is removed (error: `function` not a member of std).

Comment: Seems like a bug in the Microsoft compiler, or some corner case that isn't completely covered on the C++ standards. It seems they are treating the methods exposed with "using" as just aliases. See this thread: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c++/9gc84gCrkvw/AQw1Zv2-LKIJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compiles [**here**](http://ideone.com/7kqC3D).

I think you just forgot to add the C++11 option in you compiler.

For example, with gcc it's `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`.

**EDIT :** It seems from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14225860/1394283) that *using alias declaration* are not implemented in any Visual Studio version.

In fact, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.c++/9gc84gCrkvw/AQw1Zv2-LKIJ) some people talks about a **compiler bug.**

The weird thing here is:

```
c.foo();                                                   // this works fine
std::function < void () > f = std::bind(&Child::foo, &c);  // this won't compile
```

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I also tested this on Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2012 but to no success

Comment: Indeed. It compiles fine with TDM-GCC (MINGW) 4.7.1 with -std=c++11.

Comment: @EdisonGustavoMuenz As my edit says, it seems that using alias declaration are not implemented yet in Visual Studio.

Comment: That link refers only to `using` type aliases, a C++11 feature. `foo` is not a type, it is a function, so the `using` declaration in the OP is an ordinary C++98 one.

Comment: @Oktalist they talk [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.c++/9gc84gCrkvw/AQw1Zv2-LKIJ) about a bug in the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, Visual Studio won't let you take the address of `foo`, even though it is a public member of `Child` declared using plain old C++03 syntax.

```
std::function<void()> f = std::bind(&Child::foo, &c); // won't compile

auto fp = &Child::foo; // also won't compile
```

Directly calling the function still works fine:

```
c.foo(); // compiles OK
```

Curiously, this means you use VS2010's partial C++11 support to work around a flaw in its C++03 support, by using a lambda to achieve the same effect that your `bind` expression would have had:

```
std::function<void()> f = [&c]{ c.foo(); }; // compiles OK!
```

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles with `g++ 4.8.1`.  Are you using C++11?  I get the following output when I run it:

```
Parent::foo()
```

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010.
I also tested this on Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2012 but to no success

Answer (score 0):

In pre c++11,
this 'using' allows to not hide Parent::foo in case like these:

```
class Parent
{
protected:
    void foo() {}
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    using Parent::foo; // without this, following code doesn't compile.
public:
    // foo(int) hides Parent::foo without the 'using'
    void foo(int) { return foo(); }
};
```